# Find a closed-form for $\sum _{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{(r+1) a^{2^r-1}}{a^{2^r}+1}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

> Is there a closed form for $$\underbrace{\frac{1}{a+1}+\frac{2a}{a^2+1}+\frac{3a^3}{a^4+1}+\frac{4a^7}{a^8+1}+\cdots}_{n \text{ terms}} $$
> where $|a|<1$? Written in sigma notation, the series is $$\sum _{r=0}^{n-1} \frac{(r+1)
>    a^{2^r-1}}{a^{2^r}+1}$$

Could someone help me how to go further? Thanks.

Comment: thanks – pisco i did not understand please explain me in detail

Comment: A small simplification: $$S_n = \frac{1}{a}\left[(1+2+…n) - \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i+1}{1+a^{2^i}}\right]$$